# How to run TKDiff from the terminal on mac os

Tags: macos, terminal, diff

I downloaded TKDiff from http://tkdiff.sourceforge.net

I would like to use it from the terminal like i'm using the regular diff. something like:

```
tkdiff file1.txt file2.txt
```

can anybody help me with that?

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the homebrew version.

First install `brew` (http://brew.sh), then `brew install tkdiff` then it should just work

Comment: Thanks.  Any chance you can help with my question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377191/tkdiff-from-terminal-on-mac-opens-in-doc-instead-of-window