# tkdiff from terminal on mac opens in dock instead of window

Tags: macos

I followed the instructions here:

[How to run TKDiff from the terminal on mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318592/how-to-run-tkdiff-from-the-terminal-on-mac-os)

to get tkdiff working from terminal in mac os.  The problem is when I run "tkdiff file1 file2 " on the terminal it does not open up a window.  Instead, app Wish appears "hidden" in the application dock and I have to click on it in order to display the diff window.  After clicking on it everything is fine.  But I'd rather the diff window to pop open as soon as I run tkdiff.  Anyone know if there is a setting I need to change, or if I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: I think TkDiff uses X11, which means XQuartz on OSX. Check you have the latest XQuartz therefore. Then try starting XQuartz *before* TkDiff and see if that helps. Finally, you might like to try `opendiff` which is a very nice tool I use all the time. I believe it comes with Xcode, so you would need to go to AppStore and download Xcode then run `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Looks like I did not have xquartz installed, so I installed it.  I still have the same problem if I run tkdiff from iTerm, or from Terminal.   But if I launch an xterm, and then run tkdiff from the xterm, it pops up fine.  However I'm not thrilled with working in xterm (i prefer the look and feel of iTerm or Terminal in terms of colors and responsiveness).  Next, I'll try opendiff and let you know how that goes.  Again thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: OK.  I like opendiff.  And the main thing I was doing here was trying to find a diff that I liked that works with "git difftool".   Thanks for the help!

Comment: opendiff is still working for me ok, but it does something a little weird.  I get the diff window fine, but when I close it, on the terminal I see about 8 lines with errors like this:
2015-12-26 20:17:52.064 FileMerge[3652:172864] Failed to connect (delegate) outlet from (DiffController) to (DiffController): missing setter or instance variable
2015-12-26 20:17:52.065 FileMerge[3652:172864] Failed to connect (mainPrefPane) outlet from (DiffController) to (NSBox): missing setter or instance variable
2015-12-26 20:17:52.114 FileMerge[3652:172864] Unable to load platform at path ..
ANY IDEAS?

Comment: Also, it leaves an app open on the dock, called Filemerge.   Is there any way to do a diff without opening filemerge at the same time?